# MailChimp API 3.0 template sections return null using /default-content

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to get MailChimp builtin template's sections using API 3.0 and it returns sections :[] using

```
/templates/{template_id}/default-content
```

Before it, I was achieving the same sections in API 2.0 using

```
templates -> info($template_id)
```

I know we can't get whole html of template in API 3.0, but I know that we can at least get the sections.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks